# Localization in iOS with XIB (Interface Builder)

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, swift

I have searched now quite a bit on Stackoverflow for an answer, but I can't seem to find an adequate one.

So, I am localizing an App with XCode. Everything works fine, I have localized a storyboard and everything. The last part which needs to be localized are the labels and buttons in XIB Files. Here I have the following Problem:

XCode Offers me to create localized Xib Files for every language or to create strings files. Both options are fine with me, but none seems to work. One answer to a similar question stated that this does not work my design. If so, why does XCode give me the option to do it in the first place? And, what is a good and easy solution for this?

And I am using Swift, not sure if that really matters, I just thought I mention it.

Comment: What do you mean by it "does not work in my design"? If u localize Xibs and u change their labels content to the language specified, if you switch your devices language you should see the xibs for that locale... Is this not the case? Also in order to strings file to work you must use NSLocalizedString() method

Comment: I have the same problem. This seems like a bug in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with recent versions of Xcode where the simulator would not correctly pass the language information to the app, so it seemed as if localization was not working. If that is your problem, there are two workarounds:

1. try your app on a device and confirm switching the language brings up your localized strings.
2. force the language via your build scheme (Product => Scheme => Edit Scheme... => Run => Application Language)